# In ReactJS, How to change a line between span elements in JSX?

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to change a line after the 'text B'. This is a code of ReactJS.

```
<div>
          <span>Text A</span>
          <span>Text B</span>
          <span>Text C</span>
          <span>Text D</span>
          
</div>
```

The desired output:

```
 Text A Text B 
 Text C Text D
```

Output i am getting:

```
 Text A Text B Text C Text D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div>
      <span>Text A</span>
      <span>Text B</span>
      <br/>
      <span>Text C</span>
      <span>Text D</span>
      
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Memalon. I was trying </br> instead of  <br/>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span>Text A</span>
    <span>Text B</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Text C</span>
    <span>Text D</span>
  </div>
</div>
```